# Calling methods inside a class

Tags: python

I wanted to create a simple banking system using classes
I created all the classes but I don't know how to make them work
How do I run these methods?

```
#Parent Class
class User():
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age  = age

    def show_details(self):
        print("Personal Details")
        print("")
        print("Name ", self.name)
        print("Age  ", self.age)

    
#Child Class
class Bank(User):
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        super().__init__(name,age)
        self.balance = 0

    def deposit(self,amount):
        self.amount = amount
        self.balance = self.balance + self.amount
        print("Account balance has been updated : £", self.balance)

    def withdraw(self,amount):
        self.amount = amount
        if self.amount > self.balance:
            print("Insufficient Funds | Balance Available : £", self.balance)
        else:
            self.balance = self.balance - self.amount
            print("Account balance has been updated : £", self.balance)
    
    def view_balance(self):
        self.show_details()
        print("Account balance: £", self.balance)
```

Comment: You instantiate objects of the class, then call the methods, for ex. `user1 = User("me", 23)` then `user1.show_details()`. I recommend revisiting your tutorials on classes: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes

Comment: Could you explain why you think that `Bank` should be a subclass of `User`? A bank has users, but it isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

First change this bank init to:

```
#Child Class
class Bank(User):
    def __init__(self,user):
        super().__init__(user.name,user.age)
        self.balance = 0
```

then add at the end:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    myUser = User("Tom", 49) 
    myBank = Bank(myUser)
    myBank.deposit(200)
    myBank.view_balance()
```

But in this case you have only one user, your bank is not handling a list of users...

Answer (score 0):

## Calling class functions

Calling a class function in python is quite easy. You first initialize a class object and you can access all public functions in the class. So something like

```
class User():
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age  = age

    def show_details(self):
        print("Personal Details")
        print("")
        print("Name ", self.name)
        print("Age  ", self.age)

def main():
    user = User('Brody', 12)
    user.show_details()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also I think that you dont quite understand what a parent and child class actually means. Those terms are for inheritance and in your case there is no inheritance between the class User and Class Bank. You could introduce inheritance as the variables name and age are common between the two. However seeing as you may be new to working with classes, I would suggest to keep things simple for a while. 
 Happy coding!